# Is there a CSS way, or non-reflowing way to minimize the width of an element (without increasing height)?

Tags: javascript, css

Below is a photo of iMessage, sorry it's a bit oversized.  In the image, you will see that different multi-line messages are different widths.  In fact, each one seems to be optimized for minimal width without creating a newline.

[image]

The following is some code which achieves this effect very slowly.

```js
// finds the minimum width an element can be without becoming taller
function minimizeWidth(domNode) {
  if (domNode.offsetWidth < 160) { return; }
  const squinchFurther = () => {
    const startHeight = domNode.offsetHeight;
    const startWidth = domNode.offsetWidth;
    if (startWidth === 0) {
      return;
    }

    domNode.style.width = (startWidth - 1) + "px";
    // wait for reflow before checking new size
    requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      // if the height has been increased, go back
      if (domNode.offsetHeight !== startHeight) {
        domNode.style.width = startWidth + "px";
      } else {
        squinchFurther();
      }
    }));
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(squinchFurther));
}

const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  minimizeWidth(divs[i]);
}
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #08F;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>Here's some multi line text</div>
<br>
<div>Word</div>
<br>
<div>Crux case a a a a a a a a</div>
```

**Is there any CSS which will do this automatically?  If not, is there a way to calculate it in JS without waiting for reflows?**

I remember seeing at one point something about a "Reflow Worker" that could be coded with WASM, but I can't find a thing on it right now.  If anyone knows what I'm talking about, please share a link.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is not possible with CSS alone. The solution below holds each text block in a simple `<div>` + `<span>` structure, then uses [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to measure the `<span>`'s width and updates it to be `display:block` with the correct width.

It looks like there is definitely a max-width which accounts for the line wrapping, that is if "McCormick" or "interesting" were on the previous line the width would be too long. I don't believe I've ever seen messages that extend over ~75% of the screen width. I've set a max-width of 160px for this demo.

Note that there are two `for` loops so that the widths can be cached so we don't continually read then write to the DOM (and cause multiple reflows).

```js
function updateWidths() {
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.inner');
  const len = elems.length;
  const widths = [];

  // Read from the DOM
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    widths.push(elems[i].getBoundingClientRect().width);
  }

  // Write to the DOM
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'block';
    elems[i].style.width = widths[i] + 'px';
  }
}

updateWidths();
```

```css
.outer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 160px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner">Yeah, this week at McCormick place apparently</span>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner">Negative, seems interesting tho</span>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner">Some other random message which is a little bit longer than the other messages</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a really neat way to cut off some of the slack, but it still doesn't achieve the desired effect.  I've modified my post to include a snippet which has a "crux case" that should do a better job of illustrating what I mean.  Sorry I wasn't clear the first time.

Comment: @SephReed I see what you mean, but just so you know, you specifically cited iMessage which does not wrap its messages that way, it will wrap it the way I demonstrated (try sending a message like that to see). Are you sure that's the behavior you need?

Comment: I don't have iMessage, but believe that's true.  My mistake.  For my cases, the solution I have is fine (pdf renders).  But, a back story for how this happens: It's deadly simple to resize a textbox within tools like sketch/illustrator, and the result is much nicer looking with less wasted space.  Should I want (or need) to do this real time in the future, it'd be nice to have a better approach.  That's my impetus.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a trick that can be used to cause only one reflow, but it would be a bit of a doozy.  The basic gist of it is:

```
// helper fns from npm el-tool
const div = (children: HTMLElement[]) => {
  const out = document.createElement("div");
  children.forEach((child) => out.appendChild(child));
  return out;
}
const span = (text: string) => {
  const out = document.createElement("span");
  out.innerText = text;
  return out;
}


export default function minimalWidthDiv(innerText: string) {
  // split string into words with following spaces included
  const wordEls = innerText.trim().match(/\S+\s+/g).map(span);
  const thinDiv = div(wordEls);
  // set to hidden while computing width to avoid thrashy renders
  thinDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";

  // wait for first render
  requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() =>
    const numberOfLines = magicFnThatFindsNumberOfLines();
    const currentWidth = thinDiv.offsetWidth;
    const minimalWidth = currentWidth/numberOfLines;
    let bestWidth = 0;
    // figure out the best width based of the widths of the words
    // if more than two lines, the loop below won't work is most cases
    for (let i = 0; i < wordEls.length && bestWidth < minimalWidth; i++) {
      bestWidth += wordEls[i].offsetWidth;
    }
    // update the width of the thinDiv and make it visible.
    thinEl.style.width = bestWidth + "px";
    thinEl.style.visibility = "";
  ));
  return thinDiv;
}
```

The trick here is to put all of the words into separate spans so their width can be computed.  From there, it's possible to figure out the minimum width without needing a new line.